# How to correct wrong OSM data extract?

Tags: openstreetmap

I've downloaded the region data of Austria from geofabrik.de and it seems like there is some data included which lies outside the country's boundaries and has no connection to features inside it (as distinct from lake Constance for example which lies in Austria and Germany). Why is it like that and how can this be solved/removed?

In this picture you can see a line in the top left which is located in Germany and should not be part of the data.
[image]

Comment: You haven't mentioned where (which software) you want the clean up to occur.. I personally do this in Postgres, with 1) building a materialized view that subdivide the country (or rather aggregations of provinces geometries), 2) doing the same with a custom boundary of the country of interest (there are discrepancies, and I have seen provinces going missing in OSM too, + it allows keeping extra areas as you wish), 3) erase anything from the imported tables that does not intersect at least one of the previously subdivided polygons

Comment: I think there is an error in the OSM data, so I would like to know how to find out what needs to be changed in the OSM data so these features don't appear in the extracts any longer.